A hackerrank sql challenge
This exercise gived 5 table:

Company (company_code, founder)
Lead_Manager (lead_manager_code, company_code)
Senior_Manager (senior_manager_code,
lead_manager_code, company_code)
Manager (manager_code,
senior_manager_code, lead_manager_code, company_code)
Employee
(employee_code, manager_code, senior_manager_code,
lead_manager_code, company_code)

Note: read above as : Table(column, column..)
must return:
print the company_code, founder name, total number of lead managers, total number of senior managers, total number of managers, and total number of employees. Order your output by ascending company_code.
Example: C1 Monika 1 2 1 2
Explaination example: In company C1, the only lead manager is LM1. There are two senior managers, SM1 and SM2, under LM1. There is one manager, M1, under senior manager SM1. There are two employees, E1 and E2, under manager M1.
I tried myself a bit but it doesn't work, below is what I did. I didn't use join too at first until I decided to look at discussion. I didn't make short form? like how example answer use e,a. Is that that reason or is there any particular basics that I didn't grasp here?
select Company.company_code, Company.founder,
count(distinct(Lead_Manager.lead_manager_code)),count(distinct(Senior_Manager.senior_manager_code)),
count(distinct(Manager.manager_code)),count(distinct(Employee.employee_code)) FROM Company

join employee.company_code =company.company_code
group by company.company_code,company.founder
order by company.company_code asc;


Here is example answer that worked:
select  a.company_code , a.founder , 
count(distinct(e.lead_manager_code)),count(distinct(e.senior_manager_code)),
count(distinct(e.manager_code)),count(distinct(e.employee_code))
from company a 
join employee e on e.company_code =a.company_code
group by a.company_code,a.founder
order by a.company_code asc;


Thank you
The above is mine while below is example. If anyone kind to explain why mine not working, that would be helpful
Sorry: I realised I didn't put expectaction;

"but it doesn't work": what does that mean? What is expected to happen?

The syntax of your first query is not correct. join needs to mention the table and the join condition should follow an on keyword. You are also referencing tables that are not in the from clause. Have you read the documentation on the SQL SELECT statement?

distinct isn't a function, it's a set quantifier. Simply write count(distinct e.lead_manager_code) to make code clearer - for everyone!

I'd try group by in subqueries, before joining.

This part is bad:
join employee.company_code =company.company_code

because you mixed up the join specification with the join condition. Instead, you wanted:
join employee on employee.company_code =company.company_code

So after the join keyword you specify which table you are joining with (optionally with an alias) and then you have the on keyword followed by the join condition, which specifies which records to include into the result.

Thank you for the explainations, I realised the join..on.. was one of the mistake from the comments. Another problems is I understood wrongly regarding selecting multiple table. I will revise on this.
For this question I'm supposed to just use Company and Employee table because it'll contain all relation needed for the count.
instead of Lead_Manager.lead_manager_code, I must use Employee.lead_manager_code

@ShyCoffee happy to help
